# get the last inserted id and populate / insert into another table with that id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

The last id result is returning null, how do I get the last inserted id and populate / insert into another table with that id

The 2nd table has two columns primary key and a column for the userid from the first table.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email }, false);
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

            UserProfile obj = db.UserProfiles.Last(x => x.UserId == model.UserId);                    
            db.Profiles.Add(new Profile { UserID = obj });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
          // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your current model's UserId is null?

Comment: How can it be null when the websecurity just inserted a row ? unless my way of calling the last id is incorrect ?

Comment: Your `model` does not know it because `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` does not return you the ID of the user just created. So your model.UserId is never set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are getting UserData from UI

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
```

your model will not have Id of user, but it will be created when you insert record in database. So your model.UserId would be null.

You can get it like this :

```
UserProfile lastUser = db.UserProfiles.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserId).FirstOrDefault();                  
            db.Profiles.Add(new Profile { UserID = lastUser.UserId });
            db.SaveChanges();
```

You can also get it using Max function :

```
var lastUserId = db.UserProfiles.Max(u => u.UserId);
```

but you should get result if user record inserted suscessfully.

Comment: now I get a {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Profile'."} .. what does this mean ?

Comment: please check your connection string. Might be possible that your code is looking in the wrong database, make sure it is calling the correct database and not any auto-generated database.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is your `UserId` is never actually set therefore

```
x.UserId == model.UserId
```

will always return an empty result.

It's generally not a great idea to simply "*pull down the latest*" because you could potentially end up with the wrong ID e.g. what if someone creates a new account just before you query the DB?

A more robust approach is to simply request the ID of the newly created account using the information already available to you

```
var newUserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.UserName);
var profile = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == newUserId);
```

Comment: you are rigt, if multiple users are working with the application then this is better to do